# How to forward .gitlab-ci ssh-add command in gitlab pipeline?

Tags: docker, ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci, ssh-agent

The `before_script`in my .gitlab-ci.yml file stops while waiting for a password phrase.

- I already added the private ssh key as an environment variable
- I added the public key on the server
- I do not need a passphrase when connecting to the server via ssh

Here is my script i use:

```
image: docker:git

before_script:
  - 'which ssh-agent || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
  - eval $(ssh-agent -s)
  - echo "$SSH_PRIVATE_KEY" | tr -d '\r' | ssh-add - > /dev/null
  - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
  - chmod 700 ~/.ssh
```

I get the following prompt: "Enter passphrase for (stdin):"

[image]

Since the private key does not have any passphrase I assume the ssh-agent asks me if I want to add a new passphrase to my private key. How can I forward this prompt without providing any passphrase?

Comment: According to the [ssh-add source code](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/ssh-add.c#L232), it prompts for a passphrase if it can't parse the key without one. If the key isn't supposed to have a passphrase, you may be feeding it a corrupt key value.

Comment: Kenster - your comment seems like an answer. Can you provide it as an answer?